# What is Spring Equivalent to java.net.Authenticator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a method that looks like this, and is used by the client in the manner shown in the 2nd code snippet.  I am using Spring beans in my app, so I am wondering if Spring has their own way of doing this?  I can inject the username/password easily enough, but I am wondering if there is a Spring-centric approach.

The client is accessing a password protected URL that is hosting a web service on a private network.

```
import java.net.Authenticator;

public class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String promptString = getRequestingPrompt();
        String hostname = getRequestingHost();
        InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
        int port = getRequestingPort();

        String username = "myusername";
        String password = "mypassword";
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
```

Comment: google spring-security.  it's too involved an answer to post here, but there's an entire security framework that's a subproject of spring.

Comment: I am aware of that project - at first glance, it seems like overkill for what I need to do here.